# Explicit description of injective hulls

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-modules

Let $k$ be a field, let $R:=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and
consider the $R$-module $M:=R/{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}\cong k$.
Then the injective hull $I_M$ of $M$ admits the following explicit description:
$$
I_M = k[x_1^{-1},\ldots,x_n^{-1}].
$$
Here, $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}\in R$ acts on $x_1^{b_1}\cdots x_n^{b_n}\in I_M$ by
$
\Pi_i x_i^{a_i}\cdot\Pi_i x_i^{b_i}=
\Pi_i x_i^{a_i+b_i}$ if all the $a_i+b_i$ are $\le 0$, and
by zero otherwise.
There's also a more functorial description of $I_M$.
Let $R^\wedge:=R_{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)}^\wedge=k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ be the completion of $R$ along $M$, viewed as a topological ring with its adic topology.
Then
$$
I_M = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathit{cts}}(R^\wedge,k),
$$
where the subscript $cts$ means continuous homomorphisms.
This 2<sup>nd</sup> description makes it obvious, e.g., that the group of automorphisms of $R^\wedge$ acts on $I_M$.

> **Question.** Let $R$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra.
>   Let $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a closed point,
>   and let $M:=R/\mathfrak p$.
>   It is true that
>   $$
> \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathit{cts}}(R_{\mathfrak p}^\wedge,k).
> $$
>   is the injective hull of $M$?

More general question:
Let $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a prime ideal which is not maximal, and let $M$ bethe field of fractions of $R/{\mathfrak p}$, viewed as an $R$-module. Is there a description of the injective hull of $M$ along the same lines?

Comment: An alternate version of the first description, to easier see the $R$-module structure is to define $R'=R[x_1^{-1},...,x_n^{-1}]$ and set $I=R'/pR'$. Another version invariant under automorphisms of $R$ is $R_p/pR_p$. But the first has the nice property that $R'$ is finitely generated as a ring and $R_p$ isn't.

Comment: @Ben Wieland. I'm not sure I agree with you. What do you mean exactly by $pR'$? I'm also not sure about the $R_p/pR_p$ description. Do you really sand by what you wrote?

Comment: By the product of a ring and an ideal in a subring, I mean the ideal in the big ring generated by the elements of the idea. By $R_p$ I mean the localization. The completion should also work.

Comment: @Ben Wieland. I think I was confused by your notation $R[x_1^{-1},...,x_n^{-n}]$ (given that $x_1,...,x_n\in R$). If I understand you correctly, by $R[x_1^{-1},...,x_n^{-n}]$ you don't mean the localisation of $R$ where you invert the $x_i$. You just want to add the $x_1^{-1},...,x_n^{-n}$ as extra independent variables. But then I'm not quite sure that $pR'$ is the correct way of describing the thing one needs to mod out by...

Comment: I was very confused. We certainly do not want to take the quotient by an ideal in a bigger ring, because we do not want a ring. I guess for $n=2$ it should be $R[x^{-1},y^{-1}]/(pR[x^{-1}]+pR[y^{-1}])$, which is obviously an $R$-module. My main concern is that it is not obvious that one can divide by $x+y$. I would like to invert every nonzero element of $p$ to make it more natural, but this would require changing the submodule in the quotient. Maybe choose reps of $p^2-p$ and invert all of them and mod out by submodules that omit each one in turn?

Comment: @Ben Wieland. I agree that it's not obvious that one can divide by $x+y$... but one can! The description in terms of $Hom_{cts}(R^\wedge,k)$ makes it obvious that $x$ and $y$ and $x+y$ all have equal status. Clearly, one can divide by $x$. Therefore, one can also divide by $x+y$.

Comment: I think the section on Matlis theory in Lam's book has results describing injectives in terms of completions